# Retrofit client and response with Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit2, transfer-encoding

I'm working on a Android sample app that get film list from  http://www.omdbapi.com/.

The REST service is:

```
http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=star&apikey=d497e644
```

I'm using Retrofit to write the client.

```
public interface OmdbApi {
    @Streaming
    @GET("./")
    @Headers({"Cache-control: no-cache"})
    Call<Search> search(@Query("s") String search, @Query("apikey") String apiKey);

    @Streaming
    @GET("./")
    @Headers({"Cache-control: no-cache"})
    Call<FilmDetail> getFilm(@Query("i") String uid, @Query("apikey") String apiKey);
}
```

The complete source code is available [here](https://github.com/xcesco/kripton-examples/tree/master/film-finder).

When I run the application, I obtain the following response (taken from logcat):

```
OK http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=star&apikey=d497e644 (108ms)
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
Expires: Sat, 26 May 2018 14:28:18 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 25 May 2018 05:39:04 GMT
Vary: *, Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
CF-Cache-Status: HIT
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 4208b00c817b3db9-MXP
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

And the following error:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1Codec.java:455)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:47)
okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.java:57)
okio.InflaterSource.refill(InflaterSource.java:102)
okio.InflaterSource.read(InflaterSource.java:62)
okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.java:80)
okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:237)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:91)
com.abubusoft.filmfinder.service.repository.FilmRepository.lambda$findFilm$0$FilmRepository(FilmRepository.java:18)
com.abubusoft.filmfinder.service.repository.FilmRepository$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source:20)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

After a bit of investigation, I found that the problem is that the response has `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more investigation:

- I remove the `@Streaming` annotations.. they aren't useful.
- Tests that I did was on an emulator on a PC behind a firewall.
- `OkHttp` had some problem about it many years ago, but now chunked transfer is completely managed.
- On the same machine, invoking the same URL in a browser does not present any problems

I finally try on another machine, with a JUnit test and in Android emulator and I had no problem.

At last, I'm sure that code works, so is the environment that I used to develop the app has some problem with transfer-encoding chunked.

Complete source code is available here:

1. [android app](https://github.com/xcesco/kripton-examples/tree/master/film-finder)
2. [junit test](https://github.com/xcesco/kripton/blob/v4.x/kripton-retrofit-converter/src/test/java/com/abubusoft/kripton/retrofit3/TestOmdb.java)

I have to find exactly what is the problem, I'm sure now that it not Retrofit or my client definition or OkHttp.

I hope my experience can help other developers.

Byez